# How to create users in mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and I would like to ask one thing: if I want to connect remotely, should I have a localhost user and another with %?
i.e dba@localhost and dba@% or can I do without @localhost?

I have created both users in mysql and works fine, but I want to know if its necessary to create both.

Comment: The main reason you would create multiple users, is to give them _different_ access privileges. If the connect from "remote" is only necessary to _display_ data, but not to create or modify it - then you would give that remote user only rights to select data. And if the actual editing of the data happens "internally" (like, in an intratnet), then your "local" DB user gets the rights to write and modify data as well. That keeps your application safer, if the remote user should ever get compromised.

Comment: Now if remote and local both need to be able to perform the same tasks, then that distinction of course would make less sense to begin with, and you might rather go with just one user that has access from both locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create seperate user if you already have one for %. Using % as host covers all IP adresses including local and remote.

Comment: And of course also all of all hackers ;)

Comment: True... Including but not limited to: Hackers, automated malicious bots, even people might accidentally mistyped it's own server IP :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, so I'll try only with user with %